# Nginx does not serve gzipped content

Tags: javascript, nginx, compression, webserver, gzip

I've a problem with nginx 1.13.3 (running as docker container) and gzipped content. The server does not sent the compressed file. Hours of searching and trial and error does not fix this problem:

- I have a simple index.html with only one script tag to a javascript file.
- This javascript file is already gzipped on fs (gzip: ~360KB, uncompressed: ~1,2MB)

What I expect:

1. If I have no further nginx configuration the js file is served as is and I get a parse error in the browser. => This "works" as expected
2. I configure the following (or another location block which matches the js file):

   ```
   if ($uri = "/main.js") {
       add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
   }
   ```

This serves the file with the full 1,2 MB and no Content-Encoding header. The Browser (Firefox in this case, but also in Chrome) sends the following request headers:

```
User-Agent      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept          "*/*"
Accept-Language "en,de;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3"
Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate"
Connection      "keep-alive"
Pragma          "no-cache"
Cache-Control   "no-cache"
```

Response headers:

```
Server          "nginx/1.13.3"
Date            "Mon, 24 Jul 2017 19:35:01 GMT"
Content-Type    "text/plain"
Last-Modified   "Mon, 24 Jul 2017 19:06:10 GMT"
Connection      "keep-alive"
Etag            "\"59764522-53db0\""
Accept-Ranges   "bytes"
Content-Length  "1281624"
```

But the request log shows the content length of the compressed file:

```
GET /main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 343472
```

I've also tried to use ad-hoc compression with "gzip on" and the corresponding filetypes with an uncompressed file, but this also does not work.

The full nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
     server {
          listen       80;
          server_name  localhost;
          # gzip off;
          #gzip_types text/plain application/javascript;

          location / {
              index     index.html  index.htm;
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
              add_header X-URI $uri;

              if ($uri = "/main.js") {
                  add_header Content-Encoding gzip;
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong. I've configured gzip compressions like this with nginx several times before, and it always worked....

Thanks!